# SharePoint 2010 connection with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2010, server-explorer

I'm trying to connect to my SharePoint website with the SharePoint Connections tab under Server Explorer. It seems that the connection is being picked up correctly by VS2015; however, when I try to open the sub-folders in the website folder I get the following error:

> Server Explorer
>
> Unable to retrieve information for this node, possibly because the
>   node has been deleted or its connection disrupted. If the item exists
>   in SharePoint, be sure it is accessible.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. Start -> Search SharePoint 2010 Central Administration
2. Under Application Manager -> Manage Web Applications
3. In Ribbon under Policy -> User Policy
4. Add User